# JUST for JSON Loop arrays while looping through an array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, transform

I'm trying to create a [JUST](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1187172/JUST-JSON-Under-Simple-Transformation) transform that will loop through an array, **rows**, that is within another array, **vars.**

Source:

```
{
   "vars":[
      {
         "table":"mytable",
         "rows":[
            {
               "col1":"test val 1.1",
               "col2":"test val 1.2",
               "col3":"test val 1.3",
               "col4":"test val 1.4"
            },
            {
               "col1":"test val 2.1",
               "col2":"test val 2.2",
               "col3":"test val 2.3",
               "col4":"test val 2.4"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The transformed result is the same format with different names for the rows.

```
{
   "vars":[
      {
         "table":"mytable",
         "rows":[
            {
               "diff_col1":"test val 1.1",
               "diff_col2":"test val 1.2",
               "diff_col3":"test val 1.3",
               "diff_col4":"test val 1.4"
            },
            {
               "diff_col1":"test val 2.1",
               "diff_col2":"test val 2.2",
               "diff_col3":"test val 2.3",
               "diff_col4":"test val 2.4"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I have tried this as my JUST map:

```
{
   "vars":{
      "#loop($.vars)":{
         "table":"#currentvalueatpath($.table)",
         "rows":{
            "#loop(#currentvalueatpath($.rows))":{
               "diff_col1":"#currentvalueatpath($.col1)",
               "diff_col2":"#currentvalueatpath($.col2)",
               "diff_col3":"#currentvalueatpath($.col3)",
               "diff_col4":"#currentvalueatpath($.col4)"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But I get the error, "Unexpected character while parsing path indexer: $".  It seems to be stopping on this line:

```
"loop(#currentvalueatpath($.rows))": {..}
```

Is this supported?  What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be wonderful.
Thanks

I have tried accessing the row var directly within the loop, but it is not allowed either.

```
{
   "vars":{
      "#loop($.vars)":{
         "table":"#currentvalueatpath($.table)",
         "rows":{
**            "#loop($.rows)":{**
               "diff_col1":"#currentvalueatpath($.col1)",
               "diff_col2":"#currentvalueatpath($.col2)",
               "diff_col3":"#currentvalueatpath($.col3)",
               "diff_col4":"#currentvalueatpath($.col4)"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JUST does not currently support processing a loop within a loop.  If this changes, please post a solution here.